# QSORT function in C

Tags: c, pointers, qsort

In the following code, once I remove the commented part which compares strings, I am getting a seg 11 fault. I am unable to understand why! Rest of the code is working fine. Any help is appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare_scores_desc(const void* scorea, const void* scoreb){
int a = *(int*)scorea;
int b = *(int*)scoreb;
return a-b;
}

int compare_names(const void* namea, const void* nameb){
char** a = *(char**)namea;
char** b = *(char**)nameb;
return strcmp(*a,*b);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
int scores[7] = {456,234,65,563,67,19,100};
int i;
qsort(scores,7,sizeof(int),compare_scores_desc);
puts("\nThese are the scores in order : \n");
for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    printf("%i\n",scores[i]);
char *names[] = {"Krishna","Rama","Bhishma","Arjuna"};
/*qsort(names,4,sizeof(char*),compare_names);*/
puts("------------------");
puts("The names in order are : \n");
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    printf("%s\n",names[i]);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `compare_names()`, you are inappropriately dereferencing the arguments after the cast. The types for the local variables are type `char **`, but you are casting the arguments as `char **` and  dereferencing that results in a `char *`.

`namea` and `nameb` are pointers to the elements of your array `names[]` declared in `main()`. That means, their types are actually pointer to `char *`. When you dereferenced these arguments but assigned them to a `char **`, you cause the local variable to treat the `char *` as a `char **` (your compiler should have issued a diagnostic warning you about this problem). Now, you take a pointer value that is a `char *`, and dereference it when you pass it to `strcmp()`. This causes the program to treat `sizeof(char *)` bytes of the string as a pointer value for the `strcmp()` function. Since 4 or 8 (or whatever `sizeof(char *)` is) bytes consisting of printable characters reinterpreted as a pointer value rarely yields a valid pointer, when `strcmp()` tries to use those pointers, a segmentation fault occurs.

One possible fix is to not dereference when you initialize your local variables. However, the arguments are `const void *`, so you can avoid the cast altogether if you declare your local variables to be a pointer to a `const` type:

```
int compare_names(const void* namea, const void* nameb){
char* const * a = namea;
char* const * b = nameb;
return strcmp(*a,*b);
}
```

Note that your implementation of `compare_scores_desc()` fails if `a - b` results in signed integer overflow. For example, if `a` is `INT_MAX` and `b` is `-1`. You should fix your implementation to work for all cases.

```
int compare_scores_desc(const void* scorea, const void* scoreb){
const int *a = scorea;
const int *b = scoreb;
return (*a > *b) - (*a < *b);
}
```

Comment: @Kaz: I had seen it before, but I really took it to heart when i read [Ambroz's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10997428/315052).

Comment: There is no need for this `char * const *` business here at all. The pointers inside the array are not const qualified (and the array cannot possibly be sorted if they are!).  The callback function passes const-qualified pointers for some unclear reason, perhaps to say "please don't modify the array elements while I am sorting them because I will get confused".

Comment: @Kaz: There is no need for it except to get the assignment to work without a cast.

Comment: The `const` in `char* const * a = namea;` matches properly with `const` in `const void* namea,`.  Amen to that.  But the dereferencing of `*a` results in `char *`, which is OK for `strcmp(const char *, ...)` and _unfortunately_ OK for functions like `foo(char *, ...)`.  But `*a`, points to values like `"Krishna"` which is type `const char *`.  Thus the best declaration for 'a' is `const char* const * a = namea;`  This would flag usages of functions like `foo(char *, ...)`.

Comment: @chux: I was aware of this, but I chose to allow the `compare_names()` type to match the type used for `names[]` in `main()`. It is unfortunate that C allows string literals to be assigned to `char *` without complaint, but it does.

Comment: Thanks.  I mentally had put a `const` before `char *names[]` for I did not known one could initialize in this fashion.  It appears I am wrong.  `names[0]` is a pointer to `char *` memory that is _initialized_ to "Krishna".  `names[0]` is _not_ a pointer to `const char *` memory that contains "Krishna".  Do you concur?

Comment: @chux: The type of `names[0]` is `char *`, it is pointing to a string literal with which it was initialized. Apparently, string literals are special. They define an array of `char` (**not** `const char`), but attempts to modify the array contents results in undefined behavior. See C.11 §6.4.5 ¶6-7.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your string comparison function, and here is probably the minimal way to fix it:

```
int compare_names(const void* namea, const void* nameb){
char* a = *(char**)namea;
char* b = *(char**)nameb;
return strcmp(a,b);
}
```

The `namea` and `nameb` arguments are pointers into the string vector. You understand this, which is why you used the `char **` type.

However, all you have to do in the function is retrieve the `char *` pointers from that array. These `char *` pointers are already strings. You do not have to dereference them again; just pass them to `strcmp`.

**Your original code has a constraint violation which requires a diagnostic.** That should have tipped you off:

```
/* originally */
char** a = *(char**)namea; /* error: initialization from incompatible type */
```

You're dereferencing a `char **`, which produces `char *`, but you're storing that in a  `char **` again and dereferencing again, thereby wrongly treating the character data as a pointer.