# conversion of size_t difference into int

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion

Sorry if this is duplicate, but I can not find good answer.

I have code like this:

```
int cmp(size_t const a, size_t const b){
  return (int) b - (int) a;
}
```

I am worrying of overflow. How function must be written in correct way?

I do not need correct value, I need result to be `int` and to keep at least the sign, e.g. negative / positive / zero.

I also want to avoid any branching such those:

```
int cmp(size_t const a, size_t const b){
  if (a == b)
     return 0;
  else
     return a < b ? -1 : +1; 
}
```

Comment: ptrdiff is pointer difference? I want result to be int.

Comment: You could use a branch-less compare function using `return (a > b) - (a < b);`. See the accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996418/efficient-integer-compare-function/10997428#10997428.

Comment: @RSahu - I do exactly that, but I am thinking if there are better solution

Comment: that seems to be the most efficient solution, without risking integer overflow -- at least at SO.

Comment: @RSahu Thanks. I thought you can do something better with bit masks.